# Unity translate rotate an imported object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i can't `translate.rotate (0,5,5)` in unity on an imported model

what should i do to make it rotate i can't find a good source.

my code is here: i put script under gear or main camera but it doesn't rotate i also selected model name on script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject gear;
    // Use this for initialization


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        gear.transform.Rotate (100, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: the script is both under main camera and object ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your image, you don't do it corretly. Follow these steps :

1. Drag the Gear model from the `Assets` and drop it into your scene
2. Select the Gear GameObject in your scene
3. Drag the `NewBehaviourScript` from your `Assets` and drop it to the inspector of the Gear Gameobject
4. Drag the Gear Gameobject in your scene to the public field `gear` of the `NewBehaviourScript` attached to the gear gameobject

If you feel the 4th step is useless change the script as follow :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.Rotate (100, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, according to your image, you've dragged & dropped the gear **model** (asset) to the script file (asset). Not the **instances** in your scene.

Comment: It's totally useless to help people who doesn't know where to attach script. I usually link them to Unity tutorial since you will waste more of your time trying to explain how to do this.